# How to partition an exfat formatted drive larger than 2TB on Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

How do we partition an exfat formatted drive on Linux that's larger than 2TB?  It looks like fdisk doesn't allow partitioning above 2TB and, unless I'm missing something, parted doesn't allow exfat drives to be created.

Comment: Partitioning and creating a filesystem are two separate steps. Which one is problematic? Have you tried the plain `mkfs.exfat`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm having trouble with partitioning specifically.  I just edited the question slightly to denote that.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If I use parted to create a GPT partition and then use mkfs.exfat to format it, will non-Unix like platforms like Windows and MacOS read it correctly?  I was under the impression that the partition type and formatting needed to line up to some extent.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Fair enough.  I just did so and blkid seemed to look good: TYPE="exfat" PTTYPE="dos.  If you care to, add an answer that basically says to use a GPT partition with mkfs.exfat and I'll close this question out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59380/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-wyer33).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitioning and creating a filesystem are two separate steps. I suggest to proceed one step at a time to identify, where exactly your problem is.

You said `fdisk` doesn't allow partitioning above 2TB. That's because 2 TiB is the limit for MBR on disks with 512-byte sectors. You should use a tool that works with GPT. You mentioned `parted`, it should fit the job, at least when it comes to partitioning only; or use `gdisk`.

You may want to create a partition with a filesystem at once, because any tool that is able to do it will set the proper partition type for you. Taking the two steps independently will require you to set the partition type yourself.

In GPT scheme, the proper type for `exfat` is [Microsoft Basic Data Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition). It is identified by `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` GUID.

After you create the partition with the proper type, use `mkfs.exfat` to create a filesystem in it.